# Calculating a Fraunhofer diffraction pattern for an infinite transparency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, diffraction

The problem reads

> Calculate the Fraunhofer diffraction pattern of a piece of
> transparency that modifies the phase on the incident plane wave by
> $\phi(x) = A \sin(kx)$ for some $k$, without changing its amplitude.
> The incident wave propagates in the $z$-direction normal to the
> transparency. Describe shortly how would you calculate the diffraction
> pattern, if the phase was changed along a line that makes an angle of
> 45$^\circ$ with the $x$-axis. [Hint: The following expression for the
> Bessel function of $n$-th order can be used:
> $J_n(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i\left(x\sin t-nt\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t$]

I start as below.

```
 x         s
 ^         ^
 |         |p
 |    L    |
-|---------|--->z
 |         |
 |         |
```

Let $x$ be the transparency and $s$ be the screen, and $E_p$ be the electric field arriving at point $p$. We have

$$
\mathrm{d}E_p=\frac{E_0e^{i(kr-\omega t+A\sin(kx))}}{r}\,\mathrm{d}x\quad\left(r^2=L^2+(p-x)^2\right)
$$
and
$$
E_p=E_0e^{-i\omega t}\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{e^{i\left(k\sqrt{L^2+(p-x)^2}+A\sin(kx)\right)}}{\sqrt{L^2+(p-x)^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

As $x$ ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, it seems to me that we cannot do the approximation $r\approx L$ as in Fraunhofer diffraction. So how should I proceed?

Comment: Do you know about Fresnel zones?

Comment: @AlexGhorbal Yes

Comment: You can explain it using Fresnel zones. However, this question is now closed. If you ask another, more general question (e.g. why are we allowed to extend the integration range to infinity in Fraunhofer diffraction) then I will try to answer it when I have time.